# _firebase.db.auth is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

trato de hacer una crud con react y firebase pero al momento de registrar un usuario me sale este error: "_firebase.db.auth is not a function"

Mi configuracion de firebase es la siguiente:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore';

var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDWgfet7OjyjiFkT-SfgP0M_nKA",
      authDomain: "tasks-app-c1c23.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://tasks-app-c1c23.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "tasks-app-c1c23",
      storageBucket: "tasks-app-c1c23.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1018497030402",
      appId: "1:1018497030402:web:8584ee2058082d06920a1b"
    };

const fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = fb.firestore()
```

Esta configuraron la estoy utilizando en un componente funcional en react de la siguiente forma

```
import React from 'react'
import  {db}  from '../../../firebase'


export default function Register (){
    db.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('Juan', '1234')
        .then(u => console.log(u))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error al registrar ->', err))

    return <h1>Register</h1>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás tratando de llamar `auth()` sobre `firestore`, pero debes llamarlo directamente sobre `firebase`.

Una solución sería exportar la variable `fb` desde la configuración y usarla en el componente funcional:

```
fb.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...)
```

Comment: exporte la constante fb de la siguiente forma "export const fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);" y la importe desde mi componente y la utilice "fb.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('Juan', '1234')" pero aun asi sigue sin funcionar, error: "firebase.fb.auth is not a function"

Comment: Intenta con "firebase.auth()" directamente, te toca importar firebase desde el componente: import firebase from 'firebase/app'